# Focus html mobile

Tags: html, angular, web

I am looking for a way to place the  focus on an input field, without having the keyboard of the phone shown. The same as autofocus but after the page is initialised. Not focus() because like I said I don't want the keyboard to be shown. Does anyone know a way to do that? I am working with angular 5 if it can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found a way using a Timeout of about 100 milliseconds. On click I put the input field in readonly, which does not show the keyboard, then after the timeout, I remove the readonly allowing the input but not the printing of the keyboard.